# multipart formData String to json

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, multipartform-data

is there a way **to convert a multipart- form data as string to json object** ,or any way to parse multipart-form data in node js 
there are multiple modules but unable to find the suitable one.

My form data -

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryZfql9GlVvi0vwMml\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"key1\"\r\n\r\nabcd\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryZfql9GlVvi0vwMml\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"key2\"\r\n\r\nxyz\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryZfql9GlVvi0vwMml--
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that and there are useful modules for that:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiparty
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

If you need connect-style middleware (like for Express) then see:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-busboy
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-multiparty

Comment: All of these modules are used to get the response from a call in multipart and then convert it into json but the problem is i am already having the response in string and i need to convert that string into json.is regex the only way ??